# Wierd behaviour of the <picture> tag breakpoints

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools

I am doing simple thing actually, a hero header, where I am using a `picture` tag to disaplay different size of the hero image base on current screen resolution.

The weirdnest I have noticed it that in the tag I have defined a breakpoint of `640px` and `1200px`, but the browser changes the image much earlier, which means:

576px --> 640px
1077px --> 1200px

It's not critical, but I can't get any information on that subject? Is anybody familiar with that issue, and will be willing to share the cause of it?

Take a look at the screenshots:

[image: Supposed to be 640px breakpoint]
[image: Supposed to be 1200px breakpoint]

Comment: Do you notice it _without_ dev tools open? I'm wondering if responsive mode is having an effect. Using a different photo at one resolution and resizing the window could make it easier to see the switch.

Comment: I will try that, thanks. I just noticed that behaviour in another place. I have bootstrap 4 breakpoint `@include media-breakpoint-up(md)` which is triggered from 992px. I am currently on 901px in the devtools and this breakpoint is still active...

Comment: It looks like it is browser related issue. I started with looking in the wrong place - picture tag seems to be working fine. On firefox and safari, breakpoints are triggered at the right number. It is really strange I must say, I need to check the Chrome devtools behaviour with different projects...

Comment: Ok, I have run some more tests. I can see now that this is Chrome Canary related issue. `Version 73.0.3630.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)`

Regular Chrome devtools are working fine, same as Safari and Firefox